# Exchanging control of creatures that have since left the battlefield

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent casts [Switcheroo](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Switcheroo) targeting my 3/3 and his 1/1 and I immediately cast [Shock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shock) to kill his 1/1 will he still gain control of my 3/3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, per the Gatherer Ruling:

> If one of the target creatures is an illegal target when Switcheroo resolves, the exchange won't happen. If both creatures are illegal targets, Switcheroo will be countered.

This is because in order to preform an exchange there must actually be something to exchange, you aren't allowed to exchange something for nothing.

> **701.8a** A spell or ability may instruct players to exchange something (for example, life totals or control of two permanents) as part of its resolution. When such a spell or ability resolves, if the entire exchange can’t be completed, no part of the exchange occurs.